# Limit of PHPEXCEL in terms of size of file or number of records or number of sheets

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have to generate a report for approx 50000 rows per sheet and there will be minimum 100 sheet per file. I got the data form mongoDB but when starts writing to file it get timeout. So, Please suggest me what will be proper way to generate this kind of report and if there is any Limit of PHPEXCEL in terms of size of file or number of records or number of sheets. Please specify that as well.

Thanks!!

Comment: This is not PHPEXCEL limit.It is php time out. If possible try to write lesser rows.Or try to run your script from cmd.

Comment: PHPExcel doesn't impose limits other than those imposed by MS Excel itself; but PHP has limits on memory usage and execution times that can affect your scripts